# Getting frequent `No active replica has part` errors after upgrading clickhouse

Tags: clickhouse

I am getting frequent `No active replica has part` errors in clickhouse v23.8.2.7. I checked `system.replication_queue`. There is no record which might be stuck due to this error. The errors are getting resolved with another log `Found parts with the same min block and with the same max block as the missing part`. How can I fix this problem?

Comment: did you upgrade only one replica or all replicas in cluster?

Comment: I upgraded the whole cluster.

Comment: is problem gone away or still persist?

Comment: It is still there

Comment: This is only one replica, or all servers have this error in logs? Only one table or all tables?

Comment: All servers have this error in logs, for multiple tables.